# Plot Line Chart of Binary Variable Against Continuous Data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I am looking for a way to help better visualize the relationship between a independent continuous variable and a binary response variable.

I am trying to understand how I can add a 2nd y axis to the existing plot I have below.  I want to get a sense of the response rate over different numerical ranges visually.

1. How can I add in the response percent at any given histogram bin?  For example if there were 10 observations in a bin and 2 were the positive class, then this would show a response of 20%.
2. Ideally it's possible that this  would be dynamic in that I might change the # of bins.  For instance, I have 10 here, I might want 20 the next time.
3. This would be a connected line-chart with the corresponding percentages from #1 on the right y axis.

Or in other words, I want a line chart of the positive class to be displayed as a line chart with % show in Y axis.

```
library(mlbench)
library(tidyverse)
data(Sonar)   ## from mlbench
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Sonar, aes(x=V11, fill=Class)) +
  geom_histogram(col='black', bins = 10) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("purple", "green"))  +
  labs(title = "Count Left Y Axis; 'R' class percent of BIN in Right Y Axis" ,
       x = 'Variable Value in this case V33', y ='Count of Observations' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are after but the description you gave sounded very similar to a conditional density plot.

`ggplot` probably has an alternative to this, but with base R:

```
cdplot(Class ~ V1, Sonar, col=c("cornflowerblue", "orange"), main="Conditional density plot")
```

And the result:

[image: cdplot]

Comment: Yes, sorry ultimately I'm trying to plot continuous vs a categorical (binary) response.  I'd like to see the percent positive of this response over various numerical ranges.   This is in-line with that idea and helpful, but I'd like to be able to see the actual percentage of 'R' at any given numerical range of V1 in a cleaner way.  It's also helpful to have some sense of the distribution of V1 or the frequency of V1 which this plots masks.